# Посчитать методы и поля объекта

Tags: javascript

> Напишите стрелочную функцию, которая принимает объект, узнаёт
>   сколько у него полей и методов, выводит все поля. И возвращает
>   количество методов.

На данный момент сделал, только вот это:

```js
let data = {
  name: 'Корегин',
  age: 18,
  getHobby: function() {
    console.log('Корегин - это Будущий Senior-программист');
  }
};

let properties = 0;

let dataInfo = (dataInfoObject) => {
  for (var key in data) {
    properties++
    console.log(key);
  };
};

console.log('Все свойства: ');
dataInfo(data)
console.log('Всего свойств: ' + properties);
```

Мне осталось вывести, только поля и вернуть методы. Какие есть варианты ?

Comment: Условие надо вставлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `typeof` можно определить тип. Если `typeof` вернёт `function`, значит нам попался метод. Иначе - свойство.

```js
let data = {
  name: 'Корегин',
  age: 18,
  getHobby: function() {
    console.log('Корегин - это Будущий Senior-программист');
  }
};



let dataInfo = (dataInfoObject) => {
  let properties = 0, methods = 0;
  for (var key in data) {
    if (typeof data[key] === "function")
        methods += 1;
     else properties += 1;
  };
  
  return [properties, methods];
};

console.log('Все свойства: ');
let res = dataInfo(data);
console.log('Всего свойств: %d, всего методов: %d', res[0], res[1]);
```

Если для инстанса класса, то можно вот так (хоть я и не уверен в корректности подхода):

```js
class SomeClass {

 constructor () {
  this.some = 0;
    this.test123 = 123;
   }

 method () {
  
  }
}

let getCount = (classInstance) => {
  let methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(classInstance)).length,
  properties = Object.keys(classInstance).length;
 
      
  return [methods, properties]
  
}

let a = new SomeClass();

const res = getCount(a);;

console.log('Свойства: %d, методы: %d', res[1], res[0]);
```

Comment: Плюс, но для классов не сработает...

Comment: Не сработает, но ведь у ТС объект. ;)

Comment: Но ведь инстанс класса - тоже объект :)

Comment: Добавил вариант для инстанса класса, но терзают смутные сомнения, что верный солюшн x)

Comment: Я уже для классов сам запостил. А у тебя какая-то жесть с форматированием. И что-то я бы не назвал конструктор методом.

Comment: Не подумал почему-т фильтром убрать, каюс :(

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = {
  name: 'Корегин',
  age: 18,
  getHobby: function() {
    console.log('Корегин - это ...');
  }
};

let dataInfo = (data) => {
  var res = { properties: [], methods: [] };
  for (var key in data) {
    if (typeof data[key] == "function") {
      res.methods.push({name: key, value: data[key]});
    } else {
      res.properties.push({name: key, value: data[key]});
    }
  }
  return res;
};

var result = dataInfo(data);
console.log("Properties:", result.properties.length);
console.log("Methods:", result.methods.length);
console.log("All:", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = new class {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Корегин';
    this.age = 18;
  }

  getHobby() {
    console.log('Корегин - это Будущий Senior-программист');
  }
};

console.log('Все свойства:',
  Object.keys(obj)
);

console.log('Все методы:',
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))
  .filter(name => name !== "constructor" && typeof obj[name] === "function")
);
```