# Найти элемент по атрибуту data-id

Tags: jquery

У меня есть HTML секция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот её HTML код:

```
    <section class="about-us">
    <div class="about-title">
        <h2>See what others are saying about us</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="about-photo">
        <figure class="photo" data-id="1" data-text="“1orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ”"
        data-info="Pasha from" data-website="example.com">
            <img src="images/user-1.png" alt="photoUser">
        </figure>
        <figure class="photo" data-id="2" data-text="“2orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ”"
        data-info="Vika from" data-website="example.com">
            <img src="images/user-2.png" alt="photoUser">
        </figure>
        <figure class="photo" data-id="3" data-text="“3orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ”"
        data-info="Timur from" data-website="example.com">
            <img src="images/user-3.png" alt="photoUser">
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="about-text">
        <p>Нажми на фоточку и будет тебе Magic</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-site">
        <p>Здесь можно увидеть информацию о сотруднике</p>
        <a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="points">
        <ul class="point">
            <li data-id="1" class=""><figure></figure></li>
            <li data-id="2" class=""><figure></figure></li>
            <li data-id="3" class=""><figure></figure></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать чтобы при нажатии на картинку фотография становилась активной и точка была чёрной.

Это я пытаюсь сделать через JQUERY:

```
$('.photo').click(function(){
$('.photo').removeClass('active-element');
$(this).addClass('active-element');
if ($(this).data('id') == $('.point li').data('id')) {
    $('.point li').addClass('active-point');
};
$('.about-text p').text($(this).data('text'));
$('.about-site p').text($(this).data('info'));
$('.about-site a').text($(this).data('website')).attr("href", "#");
```

});

У меня происходит ошибка, помогите исправить ошибку, а визуально это выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909857/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Извините я не знаю как тут что работает, был бы признателен если бы сказали что сделать)

Comment: См. комментарий под ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.point li').
  removeClass('active-point'). 
  filter((index, item) => $(this).data('id') == $(item).data('id')).
  addClass('active-point');
```

вместо

```
if ($(this).data('id') == $('.point li').data('id')) {
    $('.point li').addClass('active-point'); 
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлександрКорегин Пожалуйста. Слева от ответа - знак "галочка". Щелкнув по этому знаку, Вы можете "принять" этот ответ.